# Above is an example of an HTTP simple request message that a client sent. Is there any problems with the message?

Tags: apache, http, https, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

```
GET /index.html\r\n
Host: www-net.cs.umass.edu\r\n
User-Agent: Firefox/3.6.10\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n
Keep-Alive: 115\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Body-data...Body-data...Body-data...
```

Above is an example of an HTTP simple request message that a client sent. Is there any problems with the message? if it's wrong what is the correct message?

Answer (score 0):

There should be two new lines between header and body.

So these lines:

```
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Body-data...Body-data...Body-data...
```

Should be:

```
Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
Body-data...Body-data...Body-data...
```

Other than that it looks fine, but difficult to say with such a vague question. Is there a problem you are trying to solve or an error message?